# Which office software is available for Solaris 11?

Tags: unix, microsoft-office, solaris

I am thinking of moving my software dev environment to Solaris 11. Which office software is available for Solaris 11? I would prefer a free one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Apache OpenOffice 3.4 **preview** builds available for Solaris 11 here:

http://adfinis-sygroup.ch/aoo-solaris-x86

http://www.openfoundry.org/of/projects/1201/download